# How to remove a child node after a certain date on firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

need to remove child (postkey) if value (date) < current time date

This is how my database looks like:
[image: database]

```
 Calendar calFordDate;
        calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String CurrentDate = currentDate.format(calFordDate.getTime());
        PostsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String tripdate = dataSnapshot.child(postkey).child("date").getValue().toString();
                if(CurrentDate.after(tripdate)) {

                    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is date comparison happening as it should?

Comment: not tested yet code have error  at (CurrentDate.after(tripdate)) for after Cannot resolve method 'after(java.lang.String)

Comment: Could my answer solve your issue @ahmedfekrykonsowa?

Comment: still have the problem the code not remove the old child node when reach certain date on firebase database take a look on my solve below that not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your answer is due to the fact that `tripdate` is a String and not a `Date` object. To convert string to date you can use a code that looks like this:

```java
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Also to remove a child from Firebase database when you don't know the value, has to be done with a code like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query delQuery = ref.child("Posts").orderByChild("date").equalTo(DateYouKnowIsThere);

delQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            dSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: did you mean by( DateYouKnowIsThere) the current date ? please see my answer

Comment: @ahmedfekrykonsowa is there still a problem?

Comment: yes please help me @PradyumanDixit is with @.orderByChild("date").equalTo(CurrentDate);   is that should  compare between 2 dates and when child"date" reach CurrentDate ass String then do acction ? it do nothing for me take a look @ my answer below

Comment: or i should convert child"date" from dd/mm/yyyy format to timestamp as (Date object) and get current local time on timestamp also to could compare between them ?

Comment: the `CurrentDate` should be in the same format as the date in your database. @ahmedfekrykonsowa

Comment: @ahmedfekrykonsowa is there still something to be done in this?

Comment: Can you tell me precisely what's going wrong so I can tell you what to do.

Comment: still the problem exist  take a look on my solve below that not work :(

Comment: very precise answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i used this code and not remove the old child node when it reached the current date (CurrentDate)

```
       Calendar calFordDate;
       calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String CurrentDate = format.format(calFordDate.getTime());

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query delQuery = ref.child("Posts").orderByChild("date").equalTo(CurrentDate);


        delQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    dSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

Comment: that not work nothing deleted after cartian date @Pradyuman Dixit

Comment: @ahmedafekrykonsowa what is not getting deleted?

Comment: postkey and it's content https://i.imgur.com/kdYVS1R.png inside posts child

Comment: postkey = user id that make user have only 1 post that post key child contain's "date" child in format dd/mm/yyyy i need that podtkey automatically deleted when  that child "date" equals or lower than current date also on format dd/mm/yyyy take alook at full class page https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/issues/291